# Events not being received in nodejs, using truffle, ganache and metamask

Tags: web3js, events, nodejs

I'm using web3 1.0, lets say this is my smartcontract:

```
contract Foo {
    event NewUser(
        address userAddress,
        uint amount
    );

    function addUser() public payable{
        emit NewUser(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

The events get fired in Remix perfectly well.

The problem is when I run a nodejs with express back-end and I try to watch the events with the following piece of code:

```
contract.events.NewUser({}, function(error, event){ 
  console.log(event); 
})
.on('data', function(event){
  console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
})
.on('changed', function(event){
  // remove event from local database
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

The first log gets called with value `null` and when the event can't get triggered. Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: What provider are you using? Make sure your provider supports event subscription. HttpProvider does not support event subscription btw.

Comment: i have this: `var http = require('http');`, is this what you mean? I am using express also. I also have websocket installed.. Could that help in anyway? I don't have a lot of back-end experience

Comment: I mean when you initiate web3 instance, what kind of provider do you pass into it?

Comment: My ganache location which is http://localhost:7545, is this the issue? What would be an solution?

Comment: I guess you are using HttpProvider then. See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#value. You can use beta version of ganache-cli for now. https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/257#issuecomment-357874959

Answer (score 3):

Former HttpProvider and ganache does not support web3 1.0's event subscription. Please check out the [documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#value). For testing purpose for now, you may use the [beta version of ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/257#issuecomment-357874959) with WebsocketProvider.

Comment: I'll try this out tonight